# in scorching heat or in the scorching heat

Tags: meaning-in-context

Which below sentences are correct?

1. By climate change, nowadays people have to suffer in the scorching heat.
2. By climate change, nowadays people have to suffer in scorching heat.

I have learned phrases like "in the sun" in the sentence "kids are playing in the sun" mean a sunny place.

1. So, does the above of "in the scorching heat" mean a scorching place?
2. What is the difference in meaning between the above two sentences?

Comment: Aside: "***As a result of** climate change, ...*"

Answer (score 1):

Both of these sentences would be considered grammatically correct; as you've surmised, however, they have slightly different contextual applications.

"In *the* scorching heat" implies that the speaker is referencing a specific or known situation. For example, if it is currently very hot outside, telling someone that you are dealing with "the heat" will convey that you are specifically talking about the weather in your location. You might also see "this heat" used in this instance.

"In scorching heat" is a nonspecific turn of phrase that refers to the condition of being in a hot environment. If someone tells you that a job will require working "in scorching heat," they could be implicating more than one potential location or situation, but regardless, it will be hot.

In the context of climate change, which version of the phrase you use will most likely depend on the scope of your statement. If you are referring to the effects of climate change on a specific area, then "the scorching heat" would be appropriate to describe that the environment of that place has changed. If you're speaking broadly about the globe, however, then "in scorching heat" would probably be preferable in order to capture that the people will be in a variety of hot situations.

As a footnote, this difference becomes much more critical if you remove the modifier. "In the heat" unambiguously refers to the weather, but "in heat" means a state of sexual excitement accompanying ovulation, often used to describe when a female animal is ready to breed. You may already know this, but given that this is an English language learner community, and since it would be embarrassing to use the latter in the wrong situation, I would feel remiss if I didn't at least mention it in passing!